# You are not authorized to access this page drupal 8 admin login page error

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

My drupal site admin page is not open. 
this error will be show  (You are not authorized to access this page)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that that you are authorized in the system?
Try to go /user. If you aren't authorized you will be most likely redirected on /user/login. 
Otherwise if you are authorized you need to check permissions for your user.
Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

DO you get access denied in case of admin? If yes then check "access content" permission otherwise reinstallation will resolve this problem as might be installation was not fully completed.

Answer (score 0):

Verified administrator role checkbox is checked in edit for user (user/{uid}/edit) and clear cache

Comment: in the page http://example.com/user/1/edit for example (with uid for admin : 1)
Checking the role administrator is selected or no